# Facebook API stops at 25 photos

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried using the limit parameter for selecting photos from albums on my facebook page. The javascript api just ignores the parameter and according to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

This endpoint does not have any parameters. So I am trying to figure out how to return more than 25 photos for albums that contain more. Here is the part of my code that returns the photos

```
FB.api(
    '/'+id+'/photos?limit=100',
    'GET',
    {"fields":"link,source"},
    function(response) {
        $(location).children().remove();
        for ( var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            $(location).append('<li><a href="'+response.data[i].link+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+response.data[i].source+'"/></a></li>');
        }
    }
);
```

If anyone can help me figure out why and or how to get more than 25 results using the photos graph api that would be great!

Comment: You need to use pagination to get the next pages

Comment: so there is no way to get it to return more than 25? on a single page?

Comment: Correct. That is why you get 25 when you ask for 100